# Create a Dask Dataframes from a strings representing multilevel dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dask

I have a massive dataset and I am trying to make dask dataframes out of a list of strings

`df_.head()`:

```
A   |            B              |     C
----------------------------------------
1   | "{a:1, {b:2, c:3}, d:5}"  |     4
2   | "{a:5, {b:2, c:3}, d:0}"  |     7
...
```

Note that the column c is a string, so I have to do a `literal_eval`.

In pandas I did the following:

```
import ast

for i in range(0,len(df_),1):
    df_.at[i,'B'] = ast.literal_eval(df_.iloc[i,2])

dat = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df_)):
#Makes the list of dicts into a dataframe
b = pd.DataFrame(df_.iloc[i,2])
#Keeps track of row number
b['A']=i
#Concat with master DF
dat=pd.concat([dat,b], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Then, after this, I merge `dat` with the original dataframe (df_) based on column A.

This process takes forever so I want to do it in dask.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Daniel, do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

> dat=pd.concat([dat,b], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

In this line you repeatedly allocate a new Pandas dataframe of increasing size.  Recreating your dataframe every iteration is likely very very slow.

You might instead try using a Pandas operation like `map` or `apply` to do this operation to your input dataframe all at once.

You probably don't need Dask here.  It's better to start with simpler optimizations like the one listed above, before bringing in the extra complexity of parallel computing.

Comment: Thank you MRoklin.


Actually, the most expensive part is this one:
        ` #Makes the list of dicts into a dataframe`

       b = pd.DataFrame(df_.iloc[i,1])
       #Keeps track of row number
       b['A']=i


And I am doing it this way because I want to add the identifier to b, because all the dictionaries in df_.B have different lengths.